# Implementing Progressive Web App's cached webpages using cache manifest in IOS

Tags: ios, cache-manifest, progressive-web-apps, application-cache

As we know that IOS doesn't have any support for service workers so working offline feature of PWA doesn't really work on IOS.
So my question can we implement the same functionality using Cache Manifest or Application Cache in IOS ?

Answer (score 3):

PWA is a term that puts together several technologies like: offline support, add to homescreen, push notifications, background sync, etc.

The appcache supported by Safari will help a bit with the offline support, but unfortunately you won't have the same kind of features you have with service workers.

Some serviceworker tools allow you to fallback to appcache, but you will be missing the rest of the features that will your PWA rock.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , add to homescreen is working just fine and for the time being I just need offline support to work , can you please let me know the fallbacks